# What is the Json.NET Mono assembly reference?

Tags: mono, json.net

I am trying to compile this Json.NET code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
MyDesc d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDesc>(jsonInput);
...
```

with this command via mono (on ubuntu):

```
$ mcs Main.cs -lib:/home/username/JsonNET/Net40/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

But i am getting "no assembly reference"-error:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Newtonsoft' could not be found.
Are you missing an assembly reference
```

What is the correct Json.NET Mono assebmly reference?

(-lib option looks right for this, but it does not work `-lib:PATH1[,PATHn]   Specifies the location of referenced assemblies` )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mono compiler command to reference other assemblies is `-r:PATH/TO/ASSEMBLY`. You should try this with the current version of mono.

```
$ mcs Main.cs -r:/home/username/JsonNET/Net40/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

Reference: http://linux.die.net/man/1/mcs or type into your shell:

```
$ man mcs
```

Comment: It compiles! But i can not run my exe anymore: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json. Not sure if it related. Thank you, it compiles.

Comment: As with .NET on Windows you need a copy of the DLL next to your executable or must use one of the mechanisms to tell mono where to find the DLL.

Comment: Why don't you open a new thread for your problem or at least give me some insight to help you?

Comment: Another possible location for the DLL is: /usr/lib/cli/Newtonsoft.Json-5.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Comment: @RickNZ Thank you. This was the location it installed to when using `sudo apt-get install Newtonsoft.Json`.