# Convert the string containing array and dict into the list and vice versa in c#

Tags: c#

**How can we convert the following string into a list and vice versa in c#?**

```
String1: "['hello', 'world', 100, 12.59, [1, '2', ['3', 4, {'key': 'value'}]]]"

Expected List1: ['hello', 'world', 100, 12.59, [1, '2', ['3', 4, {'key': 'value'}]]]
```

---

**Expected results:**

```
Console.WriteLine(List1[0])               //Output: 'hello'

Console.WriteLine(List1[4][2][1])         //Output:  4

Console.WriteLine(List1[4][2][2]['key'])  //Output: 'value'
```

---

**Note:**

In **python**, we have an **eval(expression)** method to convert the **string into a list**.

we have a **repr(obj)** method to convert the **list back into a string**.

Please refer to the below sample code using python methods. I require similar methods in c#.

```
>>> str1="['hello', 'world', 100, 12.59, [1, '2', ['3', 4, {'key': 'value'}]]]"
>>> list1=list(eval(str1))
>>> list1
    ['hello', 'world', 100, 12.59, [1, '2', ['3', 4, {'key': 'value'}]]]
>>> list1[4][2][2]['key']
    'value'
>>> list1[4][2][0]
    '3'
>>> str2=repr(list1)
>>> str2
    "['hello', 'world', 100, 12.59, [1, '2', ['3', 4, {'key': 'value'}]]]"
```

Each and every solution will be appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why dont you use [json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)(<link)?

Comment: When I try to include `using System.Text.Json`, it gives an error `The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Text'. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

Comment: JSon can be linked using NuGet and NewtonSoft. JSon would be more convenient.. but I think the JSon libs will not handle your strings, because they that are actually Python constants evaluated with Python eval(). Best way seems to let Python translate the data to Json first and export that to C# and deserialize with NewtonSoft. Else, you would be required to build your own C# parser for these strings.

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve the problem? if so, please mark it as accepted by ticking the V to its left. If not, please let me know and I'll try to further help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Newtonsoft.Json` library to achieve that. You need to deserialize the string as a `JArray`, as follows:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var arr = "['hello', 'world', 100, 12.59, [1, '2', ['3', 4, {'key': 'value'}]]]";
    var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(arr);
    Console.WriteLine(parsed[4][2][2]["key"]);
}
```

You can see a [live demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dsbaOE).

Comment: @user6677473, mark my answer as "accpeted" by ticking the V to its left :)

Comment: If I want to integrate this code in the mono for fiddling purposes, how can I implement this?

Comment: @user6677473, there's nothing unusual you should do. Maybe refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6437832/3002584), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36552982/3002584).